# How can I link my Lightning (Thunderbird) and my Office365 calendars?

Tags: thunderbird, compatibility, calendar, office365, lightning

My organization has recently started using [Office365](http://office.microsoft.com/). I hooked up to it for email, using IMAP and SMTP, no problem (except that it's slow). Now I want to have my Lightning calendar linked to it as well, i.e. to have automated synching both ways: I want to see in Lightning whatever changes are made via Office365, and have Lightning update the Office365 calendar whenever I make any changes. How can this be arranged?

**Notes:**

- There seems to be a tutorial about doing part of what I want [here](http://office.microsoft.com/), but it's out of date and doesn't work (and it isn't a full solution even if it did work).

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your mozilla calendar to sync your office365 calendar? One way or both ways?

Comment: @Raystafarian: both ways.

Comment: You can get read-only view of the o365 calendar using lightning and ics.  In your o365 calendar settings, look under `Publish Calendar` and you can get the ics link to enter in Lightning.  However, I found this to be read-only and can't figure out how to make it editable.

Comment: @einpoklum Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @bgmCoder: Nope. IT were not keen on helping me pursue this, I was busy with real work, and eventually I left the company. I'd still upvote good answers of course...

Comment: I added a step by step German tutorial about this: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/06/03/thunderbird-mit-office365-verbinden/ if you still need it.

Comment: @kwoxer: I no longer work where I had to do this... but thanks. If you could translate the ghist of it (no need for the screenshots) and put it as an answer, that will help others...

Comment: It's already answered by another user. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you CAN link the Office365 Calendars to your Thunderbird and it is possible to both read and write to/from the calendar.

1. First, install the Lightning Addon in Thunderbird
2. Next install the [ExchangeServer Addon](https://github.com/Ericsson/exchangecalendar) in Thunderbird
3. Now refer to this thread for all of the settings[2](https://superuser.com/questions/801831/can-imap-clients-read-my-contacts-from-office-365/899671#899671).

I've done this and it works.

It even links your addressbooks.

Comment: Note that the ExchangeServer Addon is compatible only with Thunderbird until version 59.