# What are the settings for Instantbird's Office Communicator and Lync?

Tags: office365, chat, lync

We have Office365 Business and I am trying to hook up Instantbird (beta: `1.6a1pre`, which has the new protocol) to use for chat (rather than Skype for Business, a.k.a., Lync).

(Incidentally, [here are the settings](https://superuser.com/a/899671/121324) for IMAP,SMTP, and Calendars and LDAP to work with Thunderbird)

The problem is that I can't get the settings correct for it to connect.

Basically, so far I am working off the [settings for Pidgin's SIPE plugin](https://sourceforge.net/p/sipe/wiki/How%20to%20setup%20an%20account/).

Here are the settings I have at the moment, (the rest are all either blank or default; and I've re-entered the password several times, correctly):

- username:  `my.address@my.domain.com`
- connection type:  `Auto`
- server[port]:  `outlook.office365.com:5061`
- user agent: `UCCAPI/15.0.4745.1000 OC/15.0.4745.1000` and `UCCAPI/4.0.7577.314 OC/4.0.7577.314`
- authentication scheme: `TLS-DSK`

What happens is that Instantbird says "Connecting: Connecting" and the little spinner spins.  The error console says:

```
Error connecting to outlook.office365.com:5061 (Connection timed out).
```

I've also tried without the `:5061`.

Comment: Biggest issue is Microsoft neutered Lync and xmpp compatibility so there aren't many options.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has only recently started to expanded their Skype for Business API (most of it is still labeled beta).  Unless Instabird implements any of these interfaces it won't be able to use Skype for Business as it's server.  Currently the only examples I've seen using the API are web based chat clients, none of which I've seen in production at all.

As far as I am aware there no 3rd party IM clients on the market that work with SFB. The Skype protocol is proprietary as well - which is probably the reason why there are no clients.